# Angular 5 with bootstrap

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 5 , while running my application I am getting error,[Angular error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICqpu.png)

Can you please help me to solve this issue?  Thanks in advance.

This is work in progress code so few imported modules are not used in below code.

My App Module,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {Header} from './ts/header';
import {Footer} from './ts/footer';
import {DisplayModuleModule} from './display-module/display-module.module';
import {RoutingModule} from './routing/routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Header,
    Footer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In this RoutingModule is my custom module as below,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {BusinessModule} from '../business/business.module';
import {Popupmodal} from './ts/popupmodal';
import {Home} from './ts/home';

const routes: Routes = [
  {'path':'', 'redirectTo':'/home', 'pathMatch':'full'},
  {'path':'home', 'component':Home}
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BusinessModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    Home,
    Popupmodal
  ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
    BusinessModule
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

**home.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Popupmodal} from './popupmodal';

@Component({
  selector : 'home-page',
  templateUrl:'../html/home.html'
})
export class Home{
  display= 'none';
  constructor(@Inject(Router) private route:Router,
              @Inject(Popupmodal) private modal: Popupmodal){

  }
  openPopUP(){
    this.display = 'block';
    this.modal.openModalPopUP();
  /*this.route.navigate(['/popUp']).then(nav => console.log('Successfuly Navigated'),
  );*/
  }
  closePopUp(){
    this.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
    <div>
      <button (click)="openPopUP()" >Click</button>

    </div>
```

**popupmodal.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
@Component({
  selector: 'popup-modal',
  templateUrl:'../html/popupModal.html'
})
export class Popupmodal{
  display= 'none';
  openModalPopUP(){
    this.display = 'block';
  }
  closeUpPopUp(){
    this.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**popupModal.html**

```
<div class="backdrop" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}"></div>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  [ngStyle]="{'display':display}">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeUpPopUp()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        <h4 class="modal-title">Model Title</h4>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <p>Model body text</p>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="closeUpPopUp()" >Close</button>

      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->

  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div><!-- /.modal !-->
```

**Update**
I solved this issue by using  @ViewChild in my home.ts as follow,

```
import {Component, Inject, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Popupmodal} from './popupmodal';

@Component({
  selector : 'home-page',
  templateUrl:'../html/home.html'
})
export class Home{
  @ViewChild(Popupmodal) modal : Popupmodal;

  openPopUP(){
    this.modal.openModalPopUP();
  /*this.route.navigate(['/popUp']).then(nav => console.log('Successfuly Navigated'),
  );*/
  }
  closePopUp(){

  }

}
```

Comment: May be using already implemented bootstrap components will help in the future, samples here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Answer (score 0):

No provider error usually means that you should add the service to the providers part of the module or component where you use it.

In your case I guess you need to add the Popupmodal like this.

`@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BusinessModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    Home
  ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule,
    BusinessModule
  ],
  providers:[Popupmodal]
})`

I haven't tested it so you might need to keep it in the declaration (haven't tried injecting components before), alternatively try different combinations places for it. But the core of the problem is basically: for the angular injector to inject something you need to register a provider for it.
[official explication](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved the issue as I updated in my post.